# Template specialization for union type

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, unions

How can I specialise template for `union` types? Suppose I have template function

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T value);
```

I want to prohibit calling this function if `T` is not any `union` type. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I want to prohibit calling this function if T is not any union type. How can I achieve this?

Maybe with `std::is_union` ?

```
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_union<T>::value> foo(T value)
 { /* ... */ }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `std::enable_if` (`std::enable_if_t`) with `std::is_union` from `<type_traits>` for this. Something like:

```
template <class T,
   typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_union<T>::value,
   int> = 0>
   void foo(T t) {
   // an implementation for union types
}
```

Here is explanation of the [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) rule.